# Different attributes for month/day of sfWidgetFormDate and for the options of a dropdown list

Tags: html, symfony-1.4

Is there a chance to define different HTML/CSS attributes for the year and the month/day 
of sfWidgetFormDate. I want the select-Tag for the year to use class A and the tags 
for month/day use class B.

And is it also possible to have different classes for the options of a select-Tag? I have a 
dropdown list and I would like to have my default value look different.

Comment: You would have to write your own formatter for the widget or override the widget's `render()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I hoped it would be easier :)